# My CS50 code for Edges (pset4) returns just a black screen

Tags: c, image, debugging, cs50

That's my current code, which is now returning a major white image.
I added a temp variable to store the changes in the image and attached it to pixel_with_edges. This one I passed to the new image[row][column]
I also corrected the loops and the loops linked to the sum of the colours

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE pixel_with_edges[height][width];
    RGBTRIPLE temporary[height][width];

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
        {
            temporary[row][column] = image[row][column];
            pixel_with_edges[row][column] = determineEdges(row, column, height, width, image, temporary);
            image[row][column] = pixel_with_edges[row][column];
        }
    }
}




//i and j are the current pixels
RGBTRIPLE determineEdges (int i, int j, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width])
{

    float sum_surround_redX = 0, sum_surround_greenX = 0, sum_surround_blueX = 0, sum_surround_redY = 0, sum_surround_greenY = 0, sum_surround_blueY = 0;

    int Gx[3][3] = {
         {-1, 0, 1},
         {-2, 0, 2},
         {-1, 0, 1}
         };
    int Gy [3][3]= {
         {-1, -2, -1},
         {0,   0,  0},
         {1,   2,  1}
         };

    //ident throughout the circundant pixels
    for (int row_idx =  i - 1; row_idx <= i + 1; row_idx++)
    {
        for (int column_idx = j - 1; column_idx <= j + 1; column_idx++)
        {

            //checks for outta boundaries pixels, if so, skips. That avoid segmentation fault
            //*****establishes 0 (black) to the pixels outta boundaries next to the current pixel
            if (row_idx < 0 || column_idx < 0 || row_idx >= height || column_idx >= width)
            {
                continue;
            }


            //sums the RGB surrounding pixels according to the leverage established in Gx and Gy
            sum_surround_redX += Gx[row_idx - i + 1][column_idx - j + 1] * image[row_idx][column_idx].rgbtRed;
            sum_surround_greenX += Gx[row_idx - i + 1][column_idx - j + 1] * image[row_idx][column_idx].rgbtGreen;
            sum_surround_blueX += Gx[row_idx - i + 1][column_idx - j + 1] * image[row_idx][column_idx].rgbtBlue;


            sum_surround_redY += Gy[row_idx - i + 1][column_idx - j + 1] * image[row_idx][column_idx].rgbtRed;
            sum_surround_greenY += Gy[row_idx - i + 1][column_idx - j + 1] * image[row_idx][column_idx].rgbtGreen;
            sum_surround_blueY += Gy[row_idx - i + 1][column_idx - j + 1] * image[row_idx][column_idx].rgbtBlue;
        }
            }
            
        //assigns a new value for the pixels RGB according to square of Gx^2 + Gy^2
        float newRed = round(sqrt (pow(sum_surround_redX, 2) + pow(sum_surround_redY, 2)));
        float newGreen = round(sqrt (pow(sum_surround_greenX, 2) + pow(sum_surround_greenY, 2)));
        float newBlue = round(sqrt (pow(sum_surround_blueX, 2) + pow(sum_surround_blueY, 2)));

                //garantees that no color has higher assigns than 255, and attach the new pixels values of RGB to a RGBTRIPLE struct
                if(newRed > 255)
                {
                    newRed = 255;
                }
                if(newGreen > 255)
                {
                    newGreen = 255;
                }
                if(newBlue > 255)
                {
                    newBlue = 255;
                }

                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = newRed;
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = newGreen;
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = newBlue;

    return temp[i][j];

}
```

That's my current code, which is now returning a major white image.
I added a temp variable to store the changes in the image and attached it to pixel_with_edges. This one I passed to the new image[row][column]
I also corrected the loops and the loops linked to the sum of the colours

Comment: Your function fills the array `pixels_with_edges` but does nothing with it.

Comment: That code is not complete.  It cannot be tested.  Please, read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for good instructions on how to post a complete, testable sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code.

You seem to understand that you must make a temporary copy of the image to store the result to avoid messing with the original image.

As already mentioned in comment, you forgot to actually use that copy afterwards.
What is purpose of `pixel_with_edges`? It will be gone after you leave that function.

You also forgot halfway through the code that you should not mess with the original image. You store some intermediate result in `image[i][j]` which alters the data before you processed all of it. That affects following pixels.

Additionally, the loops are completely off.
Your function `determineEdges` is supposed to calculate one single pixel and return it to the caller.
Instead you loop over all adjacent pixels and for each of them you loop over the same 9 pixels again.
Those 4 loops should only be 2 loops.
And you should calculate the result within these loop but only afterwards.
And this result should not be stored in the array but in a struct that you can return.

Comment: thank you! Your comment helped me advance a lot in the code, but I'm still with problems to get the intended image. I will edit my post with my current code updated, if you are able to help me, I'd be very thankful

Comment: chatgpt helpred me with this one ....
The function determineEdges was being passed to image before it was completely formed. So once that function use as a parameter image, image was getting changed and interfering in determineEdges.
A silly error of mine, but that it is

Comment: "image was getting changed" That is what I mentioned as "You store some intermediate result in image[i][j] which alters the data before you processed all of it. That affects following pixels."

Comment: "chatgpt helped me" Lucky you. ChatGPT is not really good at programming or at providing correct answers in general. You should not use it if you want to learn something.

Comment: ... And we are not here to correct chatGPT code, show your code, and don't bother with chatGPT.